# Full text search exclude prefix

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a problem building a MS-SQL query with full text search. I try to use this research with phrases like this "secchio d'acqua".
Unfortunatelly when I use this condiction

```
contains(p.description,'"secchio*" AND "acqua*"', language 1040)
```

I obtain no result even If The description column in the table is "contiene un secchio d'acqua".

I added d' in the stop word list but nothing change.
Someone could help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the fulltext data on the table are tokenized using language 1033(1033 may be the default language on the DB).

select *
from sys.dm_fts_parser('"contiene un secchio d''acqua"',1033,0,0)

using 1033, d'acqua is not tokenized as "d" and "acqua". Instead, it is tokenized as the word itself.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your query with the 1040 and the result is ok but If I use the contains forcing language at 1040 I did't obtain the tokenization desired I have to change something even if I forced the contains at 1040?
Thanks

Comment: I have modified the language for word breaker in the Full text catalog and now it's ok!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the option "Language for word breaker" in the Storage -> Full text catalog and now it works